# TensorFlow Regression Loss Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

I have implemented a 2-layer (2x20 nodes) DNN custom regression in TensorFlow. 16 numeric input features.

Overall I am satisfied with the high accuracy achieved (~95%), but I am frustrated by the large proportion of massively incorrect outliers in my incorrect predictions.

I believe the answer lies in either the loss function that I am minimizing (currently MSE) or use of regularization (I have tried different levels of dropout and L2 regularization with little impact on reducing the massively incorrect predictions).

Originally I tackled this problem using classification, but switched to regression hoping that minimizing the MSE would reduce the occurrence of massively incorrect predictions.

Is there a superior loss function or regularization technique that I have not considered? Note: I use cross entropy for classification, but I believe it is not appropriate for regression.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion:

You could experiment with L1 (or MAE as referenced in [this post](https://isaacchanghau.github.io/post/loss_functions/))

```
loss = Sum_n |y_n - y_n'|
```

According to the article MAE should be more robust versus outliers.

You could also experiment with higher order "norms" or "distances" for your loss-function like Lp norms

`loss = (Sum_n |(y_n - y_n')|^p)^(1/p)`

Note:

1. | | denotes absolute value or module and it is necessary only for p- odd
2. n is an index which runs over the components of of your output as a vector
3. y is your output and y' is the "true" value

Not sure if that would solve your problem, but I think it is worth experimenting with.

Good luck!